# In Acts 25:13 Luke says that King Agrippa and Bernice came to pay respects to Festus. Was he referring to Herod Agrippa II

Tags: luke

I am just curious about this verse...

If he was referring to Herod Agrippa II what does he mean by ***"pay respects"*** to Festus who was a procurator?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herod_Agrippa_II

Is the reason as per below sentense in Wikipedia. Please see highlighted word...

He was the fifth member of this dynasty to bear the title of king, ***but he reigned over territories outside of Judea only as a Roman client***.

> **Acts 25:13** A few days later King Agrippa and Bernice arrived at Caesarea to pay their respects to Festus. **14** Since they were spending many days there, Festus discussed Paul’s case with the king. He said: “There is a man here whom Felix left as a prisoner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of people in history and the NT that are called "Herod" as follows:

- **Herod the Great** (born c. 74 BC, ruled 37–4 BC or 1 BC), client king of Judea who expanded the Second Temple in Jerusalem and in the New Testament orders the Massacre of the Innocents, Luke 1:5, Matt 2:1-18.
- **Herod Archelaus** (23 BC–c. AD 18, ruled 4 BC–AD 6), ethnarch of Samaria, Judea, and Idumea, Matt 2:22.
- **Herod Antipas** (born 21 BC, ruled 4 BC–AD 39), tetrarch of Galilee and Peraea and in the New Testament orders the death of John the Baptist and mocks Jesus, Matt 14:1-12, Mark 6:14, Luke 13:32, 23:7.
- **Philip the Tetrarch** or Herod Philip II, (born c. 20 BC, ruled 4 BC–AD 34), tetrarch of Iturea, Trachonitis, and Batanaea, Matt 16:13, Luke 3:1.
- **Herod II or Herod Philip I** (c. 27 BC–33 AD), father of the Salome in Mark 6:21-29, did not rule over any territory, Matt 14:3, Luke 3:19.
- **Herod Agrippa** (born c. 11 BC, ruled AD 41–44), client king of Judaea, called "King Herod" or "Herod" in Acts 12 of the New Testament, Acts 12:1-7
- **Herod of Chalcis** (died AD 48), also known as Herod II or Herod V, king of Chalcis (r. AD 41–48)
- **Herod Agrippa II** (born AD 27, ruled 48–c. 92), ruled Chalcis and described in Acts of the Apostles as "King Agrippa" before whom Paul the Apostle defended himself, Acts 25:13-17, 2632.

Therefore, Paul defended himself before Herod Agrippa II.

Comment: Thank you. what does he mean by "pay respects" to Festus who was a procurator?

Comment: "pay respects" is diplomatic speak for acknowledge the sovereign power of another in their respective territory.  It is an old diplomatic trick - if one leader "pays respects" to another, he expects to receive to same honor and recognition to be reciprocated.  This is standard leader behavior to do this if they are feeling insecure.