What were the offices of Pilate and Herod?
Was Pilate the governor of Jerusalem? If so, what was the office of Herod? The scripture I was using is Luke 23:1-12.

Welcome to the group. As this is a site about biblical hermeneutics rather than history per se, please provide at least one biblical text for us to work with.

Which Herod? - there are about six different "Herods" in the NT.  See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60300/in-acts-2513-luke-says-that-king-agrippa-and-bernice-came-to-pay-respects-to-fe/60307#60307

The subject of Pontius Pilate’s title of authority is an interesting one to say the least. Generally speaking, he is often referred to as the procurator of Judaea, due in no small part to Tacitus, who specifically named him a procuratorem (Tac. Ann. 15.44). However, since the discovery of the Pilate inscription in 1961 during the excavation headed by Antonio Frova at the amphitheatre in Caesarea, all sorts of debates have flourished. The inscription reads, “Pontius Pilate, Praefect of Judaea, had this Tiberium dedicated to the honorable gods” (Hanson and Oakland, Palestine in the Time of Jesus. Israel Museum, Inventory Number: (L’Année Épigraphique) AE 1963, no. 104). This rather conclusively named Pilate the praefect of Judaea rather than the procurator.
While the disagreement between Tacitus and the inscription has fueled some discussion, primarily where the authenticity of Tacitus’ account is concerned (since the disagreement between the two sources provides a precedent to challenge the mention of Christ in a secular source), the difficulty, if any, is a non-point issue; a red herring, if you will. Pilate’s range of authority well exceeded that of a mere procurator, whose general administrative responsibilities would have been over finances (Dio Cass. 53.15.3). We know from the existing literature that Pilate, at the very least, commanded troops and judged criminal cases, in addition to administering funds and overseeing public projects (Joseph. AJ 18.55, 18.60; Matt. 27:11-26; Mk. 15:1-15; Lk. 23:1-24; Jn. 18:28-19:16). This shows him clearly functioning as a pro legato in the same capacity as Coponius, evidenced further by Pilate’s subordinate status to Lucius Vitellius (Joseph. AJ 18.1-2, 18.88-89. Tac. Ann. 6.31-32, 6.40-41). Thus, Pilate’s broad range of legal authority demonstrates him to have been what we might call a presidial procurator, both procurator and praefect, or an administrator with military authority, which was a role filled by praefects during the pre-Claudian years (Brunt, “Procuratorial Jurisdiction,” Latomus 25.3 (1966): 463; Millar, “Development of Jurisdiction by Imperial Procurators,” Historia: Zeitschrift für Alte Geschichte 14.3 (1965): 181; Jones, “Procurators and Prefects in the Early Principate,” in Studies in Roman Government and Law, 115).
Philo, in fact, names him both ὑπάρχων and ἐπίτροπος, praefect and procurator, consistent with the practice of granting an official multiple titles, which provided the necessary legal powers to operate a district without expanding upon the constitutional authorities of any particular office (Philo Leg. 38.299, Greek text per Cohn, Reiter, and Wendland, eds. Philonis Alexandrini Opera Quae Supersunt, vol. 6, 210. Πιλᾶτος ἧν τῶν ὑπάρχων (meaning lieutenant, or praefect) ἐπίτροπος (equivalent to the Latin procuratorum) ἀποδεδειγμένος τῆς Ἰουδαίας). There are plenty of epigraphs noted by Millar, Jones, and Brunt in their respective works to show that this was relatively commonplace (Brunt, “Procuratorial Jurisdiction,” Latomus 25.3 (1966): 463; Millar, “Development of Jurisdiction by Imperial Procurators,” Historia: Zeitschrift für Alte Geschichte 14.3 (1965): 181; Jones, “Procurators and Prefects in the Early Principate,” in Studies in Roman Government and Law, 115). Thus, Tacitus’ designation of procuratorem was likely accurate, with his choice of title a mere byproduct of the common practices and titles of his own time, and Pilate should be understood in a practical sense as a presidial procurator, which is essentially a Praefect, just as the inscription says.
As it concerns the Biblical narrative and any complications some might derive from our English translations, Pilate is merely a ἡγεμών in the text. This is a generic word for governor with a meaning indicative of the general possession of authority rather than any particular title. It is used universally to describe both Pontius Pilate’s role as governor, and to describe “the reign” (τῆς ἡγεμονίας) of Tiberius (Aland et al. eds., The Greek New Testament, 4th rev. ed). The word is simply vague. In one instance you have a provincial lieutenant governor. In the other you have an emperor. The “common knowledge” contemporaneous to any individual to whom the word is applied decides the appropriate application. Pilate’s demonstrated authority, consistent with the discovered inscription, shows him to have been a Praefect, though ancillary titles, as already noted, are not unlikely.
Herod Antipas (I assume that's the Herod you mean since this question appears to have some connection to the day of the crucifixion and Jesus being shuffled back and forth between the two men) was the tetrarch of the region, made so by Augustus after reviewing Herod's will and hearing the complaints of Archelaus' relatives, and prominent Jews from the area, who all accused him of a variety of improprieties (Joseph. AJ 17.318). As a tetrarch, Herod Antipas enjoyed an authority similar to that of a king, just not over an entire kingdom. His authority was restricted to his specific territory.
Pilate was governor over the territory previously belonging to Archelaus prior to it being confiscated by Caesar and annexed into the province of Syria. Antipas and Philip still retained their respective tetrarchies. So, when Pilate heard that Jesus was from Galilee, he paid Antipas the courtesy of sending Antipas' subject to him for judgement.


Basically, Pilate governed Judea while one of the Herods (Antipas) governed the northern provinces, including the Galilee. Prior to this, Herod I had been "king of the Jews" (ethnarch) under Roman administration. He was succeeded by another "Herod," namely his son Archelaus in Judea, while other members of the family governed the northern and eastern provinces. Later, Judea was governed by a Roman procurator and Pilate was appointed to that office.
Matthew 2:21-23

21 [Joseph] rose, took the child and his mother, and went [from Egypt]
to the land of Israel. 22 But when he heard that Archelaus was ruling
over Judea in place of his father Herod, he was afraid to go back
there. And because he had been warned in a dream, he departed for the
region of Galilee. 23 He went and dwelt in a town called Nazareth, so
that what had been spoken through the prophets might be fulfilled, “He
shall be called a Nazorean.”

After Herod I's death, his kingdom was divided among his sons. Herod Archelaus became the ruler of Judea. Around 26 b.c.e., the Romans assumed a more direct control in Judea and Pilate was appointed as procurator there. Thus it is was not Herod the Great or Herod Archelaus who governed Judea during Jesus' public ministry. The Herod of Luke 23:7 is Herod Antipas, who questioned Jesus after Pilate realized that Jesus was a Galilean. This Herod was also responsible for the arrest and execution of John the Baptist.
